# Do mRNA vaccines encoded proteins get glycosylated?

Tags: coronavirus, vaccination, mrna

per recent hype around the new mRNA vaccine against COVID-19 (or sars-ncov-2) it got me thinking about the mRNA vaccine principle.
From my biochem education I've taken, that human proteins are usually glycosylated.

It got me thinking, that if the mRNA vaccine encoded proteins would be glycosylated by human post-translational machinery, would present different epitope then the not-glycosylated one.

While I understand that the polyclonal antibodies target a lot of different epitopes, it seem to me that the performance of antibody protection obtained in such way could be limited.

I've researched this a little bit and there seems to be techniques to avoid the glycosilation machinery.

My questions in essence are:

- Would proteins encoded by mRNA vaccines get glycosylated (if not mitigated)?
- If yes, then do the vaccine designers use some methods to bypass the glycosylation?
- If yes and no mitigation has been implemented, do we just count on chance that at least some part of protein surface to present the same epitope as the original target protein?

Found sources:

- https://www.nature.com/articles/s41581-019-0129-4
- https://www.pnas.org/content/117/3/1280
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycosylation

Please forgive me my English and any typos. :)

Comment: @tyersome Thanks for the pointer about the viral proteins origin - I've totally missed that.

Comment: Your memory of your biochemical education is faulty. Only certain proteins are glycosylated — those that pass through the Golgi. And if you think about it, if you deliver a mRNA to the cell, it’s fate should be exactly the same as if the virus had delivered it. Perhaps you should.